# Deploying a python application in OS X Server 2.0.23 (aka Mountain Lion Server)

Tags: osx-server, python

OS X Server 2.0.23 (aka Mountain Lion Server) already has python 2.7.3 and wsgi installed.  What is the procedure to install a python web application on that server to run under its own domain? Assume the web application has no other dependencies other than what is already installed.

I have searched the web, but almost all instructions I'm finding refers to manually installing WSGI, python and configuring apache. I'd like to understand how to use the tools provided to deploy the application.

Comment: Does it run when accessed through localhost on the server?

Comment: No, its not deployed on the server. Only my desktop machine. When creating a website, one has the opportunity to specify a python application to run. I'm interested to understand how to add my own python application to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being more of a programming question, I asked it at Stackoverflow and got an reasonable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233628/how-does-one-deploy-a-django-application-on-os-x-server) to make it work.